# Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter_input ao invés de isset?

Tags: php

Sempre fui habituado a usar o [`isset`](http://pt1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) para verificar se uma variável externa está preenchida e se estiver usa-la.

Exemplo:

```
if(isset($_GET['pag']))
     $pag = $_GET['pag'];
```

Agora instalei o [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) e dá me um *Warning* a dizer para usar a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Exemplo:

```
if($pag = filter_input(INPUT_GET , 'pag'));
```

Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)?

Comment: obs: `isset($_GET["pag"])` pode causar um aviso no php, você está tentando acessar um índice que pode não existir (deixe error_reporting(E_ALL) para ver este aviso que normalmente é omitido). é mais correto utilizar `if(array_key_exists("pag", $_GET))` e esta função deve debater com filter_input

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett, pode dizer em que situação um aviso foi disparado usando `isset`?

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Isso não está correto, a função `isset` existe precisamente para verificar se existe o índice `pag` na matriz `$_GET`. Repara no exemplo da documentação em: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @Zuul correto, ele é até um exemplo no manual do PHP, existem cenários (depende também da configuração do PHP) em que esses avisos são mostrados. Eis aqui um caso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027455/help-with-undefined-index-and-undefined-variable

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Os erros `Undefined index` e `Undefined variable` são apresentados quando estamos a tentar utilizar uma entrada da matriz ou uma variável que não existem. Com a função isset, tal não acontece. A função limita-se a verificar se existe, e só se existir é que vai verificar se o valor é `null`. Podes aprofundar este assunto [nesta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/352449) do SOEN. Em suma, a função `isset` serve precisamente para evitar os erros: `Undefined index` e `Undefined variable`.

Comment: o ntebeans dispara o warning devido as políticas de uso da plataforma netbeans. Não quer dizer que no PHP seja assim também.. é meramente devido as regras do framework. Um outro exemplo, o PrestaShop dispara warning quando tenta usar mb_strlen ou strlen ou outras funções de string diretamente no código. Eles pedem para usar as libraries internas, como forma de padronizar os códigos dentro das regras do framework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Como pode ser lido na documentação da função [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> filter_input — Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it

Que traduzido:

> filter_input — Obtém uma variável externa específica pelo nome e opcionalmente filtra o seu valor.

A vantagem em utilizar a função `filter_input` é o fato de que não só vamos recolher o valor como também podemos no decorrer dessa recolha filtrar o mesmo:

```
$search_html = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'chavePesquisa', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Útil para proceder à proteção, limpeza ou validação dos dados provenientes do utilizador sem fazer uso de múltiplas funções e diversas linhas de código.

A lista dos filtros pode ser encontrada aqui:

[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Variable and Type Related Extensions > Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Comment: Então eu posso fazer a validação dos dados dum formulário usando somente o filter_input?

Comment: @JorgeB. temos também o `filter_input_array`. Dê uma olhada na resposta que eu postei.

Comment: @JorgeB. A validação é um processo delicado e complexo, os filtros de PHP visam simplificar todo o processo mas não são 100% eficazes e podem descurar alguns detalhes. Por exemplo, o filtro `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` não assume corretamente todos os esquemas de composição de emails existentes hoje. E mesmo quando atualizada, essa função está desatualizada porque todos os dias existem novos esquemas a serem aplicados. Podemos assumir que parte do trabalho de validação pode ser realizado com a função `filter_input`, mas raramente se consegue validar tudo recorrendo à mesma.

Comment: @Zuul para essas exceções que os filtros padrões não são suficientes temos o `FILTER_CALLBACK`.

Comment: @gmsantos Correto, a _callback_ foi implementada para permitir estender a funcionalidade base facultada pelo filtro em uso.

Comment: @Zuul o que acontece quando a variável "chavePesquisa" não está preenchida? Não deveria ter um if para saber se a `$search_html` foi preenchida? Tipo isto: `$locale = ($filter = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "locale")) ? $filter : $_SESSION['idioma'];`

Comment: @JorgeB. O facto da variável estar ou não preenchida é um assunto distinto. Deves fazer essa verificação se tens necessidade e/ou estás sujeito a que isso aconteça. Por norma, se vier de um utilizador, nunca confiar, sempre verificar! :)

Answer (score 12):

A principal diferença é que [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) verifica se existe algum valor na variável, enquanto com [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) é possível fazer algumas validações ou limpezas nas entradas.

[a lista de validações e limpezas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

O uso de `filter_input()` pode algumas vezes simplificar validações, por exemplo um intervalo de idade, onde uma criança não pagaria uma passagem de ônibus, ou teria uma valor diferenciado na cobrança de uma refeição em um restaurante.

Validação com `filter_input`:

```
$options = array('options' => array('min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 6 ));
if($idade = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)){
    echo 'isento de pagar a passagem de ônibus pois sua idade é: '. $idade;
}else{
    echo 'Na dúvida sempre cobre, idade: '. $idade;
}
```

Uma forma de validação tradicional:

```
$idade = -1;
if(isset($_GET['search']) && ctype_digit($_GET['search'])){
    $idade = $_GET['search'];
}

if($idade >= 0 && $idade <= 6){
    echo 'Isento de pagar a passagem de ônibus pois sua idade é: '. $idade;
}else{
    echo 'Na dúvida sempre cobre, idade: '. $idade;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Algo que creio que ninguém tenha comentado, mas acho importante ressaltar é que o `filter_input` tem uma grande diferença em relação ao `isset`.

O `isset` vai verificar se uma determinada é existente, independente se venha de conteúdo externo ou não.

Exemplo comum:

```
// url?nome=wallace 
isset($_GET['nome']); // true
```

Porém se eu fizer isso, funcionará também:

```
// url?nome=wallace
 $_GET['idade'] = 25;
isset($_GET['idade']); // true
```

Veja que declarei um valor para variável `$_GET`, o qual não existia na url, mas apenas no código, e `isset` o detectou lá, como era de se esperar.

Agora vejam a diferença em relação ao `filter_input`

```
//url?nome=wallace
filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nome'); // 'wallace';
```

Já nesse caso:

```
$_GET['idade'] = 25;
filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idade');// bool(false)
```

Perceba que `filter_input` não é "enganado" pela declaração de um valor dentro do `array $_GET`.

Sendo assim, `filter_input` verifica realmente se o conteúdo existe externamente, via método GET. Já `isset` só verifica se o valor existe ou não.

O mesmo caso vale para a função `filter_has_var`. Então, eis aí um motivo para usá-la ao invés de `isset`;

Achei importante ressaltar isso aqui.

Comment: O laravel usa filter_has_var?

Comment: @rray, o `Laravel` não usa nenhuma dessas variáveis globais do PHP. Na verdade, ele usa o `HttpFoundation\Request` do `Symfony`. Aí, o `Symfony`, por sua vez, tem um tal de `Request::createFromGlobals`, que utiliza essas variáveis. Na minha opnião com tudo isso, eles não usam. Mas acho que todos deveríamos, já que é um recurso novo

Comment: Lembro que o laravel tem um uns métodos, `has_var` ou `except` para filtar os inputs, é bacana.

Comment: Ah, sim. Vale a pena fazer uma pergunta sobre isso, hein. `Input::only('nome', 'idade', 'cidade')`. Pega apenas esses trềs inputs :)

Comment: Exato, para previnir argumentos maliciosos na url :D. Tenho estudado um pouco laravel.

Answer (score 9):

A vantagem em usar o [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) está na facilidade em aplicar filtros em sua string.

O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com a função [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php), que implementa as constantes de [`FILTER`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/filter.constants.php)

O `filter_input` teria a mesma função que:

```
// Sem filter_input
$email = filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

// Usando filter input
$email = filter_input(INPUT_GET , 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

As funções `filter_*` são poucos usadas por iniciantes, porem elas tem bastante utilidade. No exemplo acima por exemplo, o php já valida se o `input` é um email, sem precisar recorrer a [Expressões Regulares monstras](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Com um pouco de criatividade, usando um primo da função `filter_input`, a [`filter_input_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php), podemos validar nossos formulários com um código bastante expressivo e elegante.

---

Exemplo adaptado da documentação:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'product_id'    => 'libgd<script>',
    'component'     => '10',
    'versions'      => '2.0.33',
    'testscalar'    => array('2', '23', '10', '12'),
    'testarray'     => '2',
);

$args = array(
    'product_id'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'component'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
                            'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 10)
                           ),
    'versions'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'doesnotexist' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'testscalar'   => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                           ),
    'testarray'    => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
                           )

);

$myinputs = filter_var_array($data, $args);

var_dump($myinputs);
```

Resulta no seguinte array já tratado:

```
array(6) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "libgd%3Cscript%3E"
  }
  ["component"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
  }
  ["versions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "2.0.33"
  }
  ["doesnotexist"]=>
  NULL
  ["testscalar"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["testarray"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: "são poucos usadas por iniciantes". Eu não diria isso e digo por mim, não uso pois validação é algo muito delicado e o PHP tem um 'probleminha' com algumas validações - acentos que dependem das funções MB, validação de numéricos... Por isso prefiro criar minhas regras. Mas a explanação vale +1 :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie realmente existem esse 'probleminhas', mas prefiro tratá-los como exceções. Porém quando me deparo com esses probleminhas podemos recorrer ao bom e velho [callback](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php#84326) :)

Comment: Veja a flag `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`. Você recebe `1e1`(10), e ele diz que é true porque para o PHP 1e1 equivale a 10, logo é um INT entre 1-10. :)

Answer (score 7):

Sim, e muita vantagem, já que com ela você faz a "limpeza" dos dados de entrada ao utilizar o terceiro parâmetro, que é o **[tipo de filtro](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)**. Existem diversos filtros que você pode substituir pelas validações manuais que era acostumado a fazer, como por exemplo validar um endereço de e-mail ou simplesmente verificar se uma entrada é um número.

Alguns exemplos:

```
if ($email = filter_input(INPUT_POST , 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // é um e-mail válido
}

if ($numero = filter_input(INPUT_POST , 'numero', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    // é um inteiro
}
```

Os filtros, como você pode verificar na URL acima, podem ser tanto para validação quanto para "higienizar" um dado de entrada.

Lembrando que está disponível a partir da versão **5.2.0**.

Answer (score 4):

Existe um [*bug*](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61497) (reportado em 24/03/2012) relacionado à função `filter_input()`. Alguns valores de `$_SERVER` não são exibidos corretamente. O trecho de código abaixo exibe as chaves onde o problema ocorre:

```php
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $key) != $value) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Serão exibidas as chaves `REQUEST_TIME` e  `REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT`. Para esses dois casos não se deve utilizar `filter_input()`, utilizando o acesso "tradicional" com:

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

A função `filter_has_var()` também é afetada por esse *bug*.