# Como tratar ids com php?

Tags: php, html

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                
             echo "<li class='list-inline-item'><a href='news.php?id=" .$row['id']. "'>". $row['titulo'] ."</a></li>";
             echo "<br>";
}
```

tenho esse pequeno código que busca no banco todas os títulos de noticias existentes. Como podem ver, eu adicionei também um link em cada uma delas.
Mas eu gostaria de saber como tratar cada um dos ids em uma seguinte página, ao usuário clicar no titulo linkado abrisse uma página com mais informações.

-

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_GET["id"]))
    {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $listagem = "SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $listagem);
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $linha['titulo'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $linha['news'];
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: No arquivo `news.php`, você pode recuperar o valor do `id`utilizando `$_GET["id"]`. É esta a dúvida?

Comment: Basicamente sim. Ainda to tentando imaginar como isso seria feito, mas valeu! Vou tentar procurar alguns exemplos aqui.

Comment: Para selecionar as outras informações do registro, basta fazer o `select` no banco retornando o registro que possui o `id` igual a `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: Se já existir um arquivo `news.php`, faça um `print_r($_GET['id'])` nele. Assim quando clicares no link, este `id` será impresso no corpo do `news.php`. Feito isto, podes simplesmente fazer um `SELECT titulo, conteudo FROM noticias WHERE id = {$_GET[`id`]}` e imprimir o resultado da consulta, tudo isto em `news.php`. Devem já existir aqui perguntas relacionadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após essa linha

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Faça um tratamento do valor recebido antes de prosseguir com outras ações.

Normalmente o ID é numérico, então considerando ser um valor numérico, sanitize e valide

```
function NumberSanitize($str) {
    // retorna somente caracteres numéricos
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}

$id = NumberSanitize($_GET['id']);

// Se não for vazio, prossegue
if (!empty($id)) {

    // Não precisa se preocupar com injeção SQL pois a variável possuirá somente caracteres numéricos. Portanto, pode prosseguir com a consulta ao banco.

    $listagem = "SELECT * FROM noticia WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $listagem);
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $linha['titulo'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $linha['news'];
}
```

Consulte também:

[Como validar cada tipo de dado recebido de um formulário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89960)