# Criando super class para proteção de formulário PHP

Tags: php

Estou com a ideia de tentar montar um super class para proteger formulários.

Quem tiver novas ideias poste ai para eu ir atualizando.

**Alguém acrescenta mais algo?**

```
function seguro($sql){
// remove palavras que contenham sintaxe sql
    $sql = preg_replace(prepared("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
    $sql = strip_tags($sql);//tira tags html e php
    $sql = addslashes($sql);//Adiciona barras invertidas a uma string
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $obj = addslashes($sql);
        return $sql;
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

> Versão: 1.2

Comment: Essa função é igual aquele adesivo, sorria você está sendo filmado só que sem cameras. Recomendo a leitura de: [Como validar cada tipo de dado recebido de um formulário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89960/91)

Comment: @rray Não funcionaria?

Comment: Se o sistema armazena nomes de musicas sua função vai 'comer' algumas com essa substituição, `Wherever i may roam `vira `ver i may roam`. [sql_regcase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sql-regcase.php) foi depreciada no php5.3 e removida no 7. Você pode usar prepared statements para evitar sql injection.

Comment: @rray Você pode editar o código.

Comment: Criar uma classa ou uma biblioteca para tarefas comuns é uma ótima ideia acredito que o github seja uma ferramente melhor para isso. `Quem tiver novas ideias poste ai para eu ir atualizando.` é bem amplo e não se encaixa bem no formato de Q&A. Lembre que você pode pedir opiniões no [chat do site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a biblioteca [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) para realizar as consultas e também, para proteger suas queries. No seu caso, ficaria desta forma:

```
//modo de usar pegando dados vindos do formulário
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', 'usuario', 'senha');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome = :nome and senha = :senha');
$run = $stmt->execute(array(
    ":nome" => $nome,
    ":senha" => $senha,
));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Utilizando desta forma, o método prepare do PDO evita injeção de SQL.