# Como tratar chave e valor de requisição no php?

Tags: php

Estou querendo tratar as chaves e valores do $_REQUEST que uma página recebe.

A verificação seria:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST)){
   // Tratamento das chaves e valores
}
```

Isso porque tive alguns problemas em relação a segurança, em que os valores das chaves estavam sendo alterados :(

Por esse motivo preciso fazer esses tratamentos e não sei qual a forma mais eficiente de se fazer isso.

Para exemplificar isso, segue um problema da impressão de um $_REQUEST:

```
Array
(
    ["onmouseover] => '4Puv(9698)'bad="
)
```

Comment: Qual o problema com as chaves? relacionada: [Como validar cada tipo de dado recebido de um formulário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89960/91)

Comment: mas que tipo de tratamento voce precisa? Ou tem mais aver com validacao? Antes voce jogava do form direto no banco?

Comment: Então, acredito que a função htmlspecialchars vai resolver isso para mim. O problema é que eu precisaria tratar as chaves dessa requisição e não só os valores.

Comment: Vem chaves com caracteres como `# , . ^ ~ & % $`? quer remover eles ou o que?

Comment: Meu problema é mais com aspas simples, aspas duplas que estão vindo nas chaves dos valores. Vou colocar um exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: Mas qual o problema com as aspas? Você esta com medo de sql-injection? Se for o caso use preparedStatement, se o problema também for html-injection então no momento do `SELECT` quando trouxer os dados no `while` use o `htmlespecialchars`.

Comment: Já melhorou, um dos problemas pode ser na definição nos campos do form, as vezes como array ex: `name="produtos[id][algo]"`