# validação de superglobais

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo uma classe para auxiliar o múltiplo upload usando o [framework Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) e resolvi analisar meu código usando algumas ferramentas online.

Uma delas foi o [code climate](https://codeclimate.com); Notei que ao verificar os reportes para melhoria de código o mesmo informa que não é recomendado o uso de superglobais tais como `$_FILES` mesmo em funções especificas para a validação como por exemplo;

```
public function hasFile($key)
{
   if (!isset($_FILES[$key]) {
       throw new Exception("Não existe o indice $key", 1);
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

Tentei modificar isto criando um atributo chamado `key`

```
public $key = 'userFile';
```

E chamá-lo dentro das funções

```
if (!isset($_FILES[$this->key]) {.....
```

Porém continuo recebendo o report de que isto não é uma boa pratica! Procurei também na documentação do PHP se existe algum [tipo de filtro para a superglobal](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) `$_FILES` usando a função `filter_input` e também não encontrei.

Qual seria a melhor forma de validar a superglobal `$_FILES`?

print do report;

[image: screenshot code climate]

Na função em questão eu não atribuo a super-global a nenhuma variavel, apenas realizo a validação como nos exemploa acima.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Obter variável externa isset vs filter\_input](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35508/obter-vari%c3%a1vel-externa-isset-vs-filter-input)

Comment: @JorgeB. não é uma duplicata, pois o contexto é diferente, não estou questionando o uso de `isset` ou `filter_input` e sim um método para validar a superglobal `$_FILES` que por sua vez não possui um `filter_input`.

Comment: Tens toda a razão. Esqueci-me que não funciona para `$_FILES`.

Comment: @rray adicionado.

Comment: É o CodeClimate que emite o aviso?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim.

Comment: Eu conversei com o bigown e o wallace no chat hoje, acho que "boa pratica" não é "regra", é mais como "dica". Claro que isto é a minha opinião :)

Answer (score 3):

Observando bem a pergunta, parece que você quer utilizar uma classe para poder aplicar operações de upload.

Eu te recomendaria em tais casos realmente não utilizar o `$_FILES` dentro da classe. Até porque, para esse fim, não haveria necessidade de os métodos serem dinâmicos, e sim estáticos.

Um bom exemplo que sempre gosto de usar é o o `Symfony`, que em seus códigos-fontes, a classe `Request`, `Response` ou `UploadedFile`, são apenas entidades que visam tratar os dados, independendes da forma com que eles venham - o que no seu caso seria através da variável `$_FILES`.

O que o Symfony faz na verdade é criar um método estático que inicialize uma nova instância, baseando-se em elementos globais. Aí sim, acho que fica algo mais organizado, e não-dependente de somente ter uploads vindo de `$_FILES` - você poderia adicionar `file_get_contents('php://input')` por exemplo.

Então, nesse contexto, sugiro a criação do seguinte método estático para criação da instância:

```
class Upload
{
    protected $files = [];

    public function __construct(array $files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function hasFile($key)
    {
        return isset($this->files[$key]);
    }

    public function getFile($key)
    {
        if ($this->hasFile($key)) {
            return $this->files[$key];
        }

        throw new Exception("Não existe o arquivo $key");
    }


    public static function createFromFilesGlobal()
    {
        return new static($_FILES);
    }
}
```

Assim o uso seria:

```
 $files = Upload::createFromFilesGlobals();


 $files->getFile('key');
```

Observe que, nesse caso, o `createFromFilesGlobals` é um método estático - o contrário de dinâmico. Esse método, tem como finalidade apenas devolver `new static`, passando como parâmetro a variável global `$_FILES`. Isso fará com que uma instância de `Upload` seja devolvida, com a propriedade `$files` preenchida com os valores de `$_FILES`.

Agora, imagina se você quer usar essa mesma classe para capturar algum tipo de requisição que, porventura, não passasse pelo `$_FILES` do PHP. Qual seria a solução?

Exemplo fictício:

```
 // essa função não existe no PHP, é só um exemplo
 $raw_files = parse_uploaded_files_from_php_raw_input('php://input'); 

 $files = new Upload($raw_files);
```

Então, dessa forma, você tem uma classe que não é limitada por uma variável super global do PHP, mas que apenas usa seus valores (ou não), caso seja necessário.

Comment: não entendi bem o uso desse `new static()`.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly ele cria uma instância da própria classe, que retornará ela mesma, passando `$_FILES` por parâmetro. Dessa forma, você não usa o `$_FILES` dentro da classe, mas apenas seus dados. É um padrão utilizado para inicializar a classe a partir de valores Super Globais, o que é diferente da classe "depender" de `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 1):

Em programação, na parte do tempo (idealmente) você não deve tratar ou alterar elementos externos dentro de uma função, ou seja função ou método não deve altarar que não seja passado como argumento ou que pertença a classe.

Essa 'regra' é mais ou menos como a sua mãe dizia não aceita nada de estranhos, isso inclui variáveis ou objetos :P.

Lembre que essa regra pode mudar conforme a linguagem pode ser mais ou menos rigida, pegue por exemplo javascript, uma função não acessa N elementos externos?

Acredito que a solução para remover esse warning é passar `$_FILES` no construtor da sua classe e sempre alterar/retornar essa cópia.

Comment: Essa é não uma regra de programação, é uma regra de linguagem e isso não se aplica ao PHP. Podemos alterar sim o conteúdo de uma variável passada como parâmetro. Desde a versão 5.3, se não me engano, não é mais necessário passar um argumento por referência para poder alterá-lo internamente.

Comment: @Brittz uma função não deve alterar elementos externos a sua assinatura pois isso modifica a variável de origem. Por exemplo em uma função vc da um `unset($_POST);` e depois da execução da função ainda são feitas modificações em `$_POST` que agora não existe mais um efeito colateral foi criado. Com exceções a maior parte do tempo vc deve passar os elementos globais como argumentos em funções e de preferência por valor.

Comment: concordo que é uma péssima prática alterar o conteúdo das SUPER GLOBAIS dentro ou fora de métodos e funções.

Comment: @Brittz veja a pergunta foi editada :P agora acho q de p entender minha resposta.

Comment: Eu estou de acordo com sua resposta. Quis apenas observar sobre o fato de editar variáveis dentro de métodos e funções no PHP. Estou procurando no changelog sobre a necessidade de passagem por referência para isso, pois acho que me enganei. Em todo caso, se for necessário, basta definir no início da função `global $myvar`, assim você poderá editar o conteúdo, com impacto externo.

Answer (score 1):

No código que apresentou não há uma má prática.

Uma má prática seria se estivesse sanitizando ou filtrando os dados da superglobal.

Exemplo do que seria uma má prática:

```
$_POST['foo'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo']);
```

No caso do `isset()`, não há modificação no valor. Não tem nada de errado em usá-lo dessa forma.

```
if (isset($POST['foo'])) {
    // bla bla bla
}
```

Nos exemplos usei $_POST, porém, o mesmo se aplica $_GET, $_FILES, $_SERVER, enfim, as superglobais: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php