# Qual importância de filtrar super globais?

Tags: php, post, get

Queria saber de mais detalhes do que poderia acontecer quando deixo de filtrar super globais, principalmente para inserção de dados. Quais brechas poderiam ser abertas? Comecei com php faz pouco tempo e estava fazendo um pequeno sistema apenas para aprender e mostrei o código para um colega onde uso bastante $_POST e $_GET ele já tem mais experiência e então ele me falou sobre os filtros porém não entendi direito.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Comece por aqui para entender que filtros por si só não são solução. Precisa sanitizar os valores conforme o uso: [Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50839/70).

Comment: Valeu pelo link, eu já estou usando o mysqli_real_escape_string  direto nos métodos do DAO então isso pode resolver o problema? ou estou esquecendo de algo?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Obter variável externa isset vs filter_input](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35511/91), [Como validar cada tipo de dado recebido de um formulário?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89960/91) e [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problema

Quando se constrói um sistema que trabalha com banco de dados, essa é a maior preocupação que se deve ter em relação aos dados que são recebidos pelo usuário. Por exemplo, quando se tem um formulário de login onde o usuário passa email e senha:

```
<form method="POST">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" /><br />
</form>
```

E no PHP você recebe os dados desta forma:

```
<?php

$login = $_POST["login"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '{$login}' AND senha = '{$senha}'";

?>
```

O usuário mal intencionado querendo invadir seu sistema pode simplesmente digitar nos campos isto `' OR 1 = '1` que a consulta executada seria esta:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '' OR 1 = '1' AND senha = '' OR 1 = '1'
```

Fazendo com que a consulta pegue o primeiro usuário que encontrar e entre tranquilamente no sistema.

## Solução

Para escapar deste tipo de problema que é comum, acredite (É realmente fácil encontrar sistemas com este tipo de falha), é uma boa e simples prática receber os dados de formulários desta maneira:

```
<?php

$login = addslashes($_POST["login"]);
$senha = addslashes($_POST["senha"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '{$login}' AND senha = '{$senha}'";

?>
```

Onde o usuário ao tentar preencher os campos com isto `' OR 1 = '1`, tentaria executar esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '\' OR 1 = \'1' AND senha = '\' OR 1 = \'1'
```

Que o banco de dados interpretaria como 'Pegue todos os dados dos usuários cujo login é igual a `' OR 1 = '1` e senha igual a `' OR 1 = '1`.

Fugindo assim do ataque ao banco.

Comment: e se usarmos o nessas variaveis mysqli_real_escape_string  irá acontecer o mesmo?

Comment: @ReynnanViktor é exatamente a mesma coisa. A diferença é que o mysqli_real_escape_string() é procedural e espera um objeto `mysqli` como primeiro parâmetro seguido da string que deseja escapar. E se você estiver trabalhando com mysqli procedural ou orientado, é preferível trabalhar com esta função dele sim.