# Quando usar o filter_input() PHP

Tags: php

Durante muito tempo uso o `$_POST[]` em minhas aplicações, porém tenho visto que em alguns colegas usam o `filter_input()` no lugar de `$_POST[]`. Já abri a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), mas confesso que não consegui entender muito bem o seu uso. Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Para que serve o `filter_input()`;
2. Se é válido trocar o `$_POST[]` pelo `filter_input()`;
3. Quando devemos usar o `filter_input()`;

Vi que na documentação, destaca `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`, `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED`, `FILTER_DEFAULT` e `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`. Esse último uso para validar e-mail:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"EmailVerificar",FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Porém só esse que compreendi o uso.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Há alguma vantagem em utilizar a função filter\_input ao invés de isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35508/h%c3%a1-alguma-vantagem-em-utilizar-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-filter-input-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-isset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então meu caro, primeiramente bom dia!

Conforme você já visitou [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), vou dar apenas uma pincelada bem rápida para cada item ao qual citou no tópico.

**1.-** O `filter_input()` podemos dizer que é uma junção das variáveis já conhecidas por nós programadores de PHP ($_POST, $_GET e outras) em uma única função e "opcionalmente a filtra (como citado na documentação)".

**2.-** Sim é realmente válido você fazer a troca de um **$_POST** por um vamos supor `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` ou `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SPECIAL_CHARS)` (Sendo apenas um exemplo bem básico de como poderia ser usado)

**3.-** Poderia ser usado em demasiadas ocasiões, como por exemplo em um **$_GET** e verificando se o *$_GET* é numérico...
`$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

Mas temos um porém se acaso o index não existe... Nessa ocasião:

`$foo = filter_var($_GET['foo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

Retorna uma string `""` vazia e gera:

> Notice: Undefined index: foo

O nosso atual, seguindo os parâmetros da documentação, vai retornar apenas um `NULL` resultado:

`$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

Retorna apenas:

> NULL

Mas basicamente a resposta é: **SIM**, você pode efetuar uma simples troca do seu `$_POST` pelo `filter_input()`. (Inclusive uso em meus projetos! Kkk)

---

Apenas somando as informações (Em agradecimento ao @Fox.11 por ter postado) caso haja demasiadas dúvidas em relação as duas opções de filtro.

**FILTER_SANITIZE**

Usado para limpar as variáveis:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4AnuYaSWO4

**FILTER_VALIDATE**

Usado para validar as variáveis:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J8lOhc1_IA

Comment: Bom dia Rapha. Obrigado! Apenas para somar com suas informações, encontrei 02 vídeos que podem ajudar pessoas que, assim como eu, tem dúvidas em relação ao `filter_input()`. São eles: **FILTER_SANITIZE** Usado para limpar as variáveis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4AnuYaSWO4 **FILTER_VALIDATE** Usado para validar as variáveis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J8lOhc1_IA Vale a pena dar uma olhada.